# Programming - battery energy logging; creating negative and positive data output from a single sensor

Tags: batteries, programming, energy, datalogger

I'm using a single bidirectional Hall effect sensor to read the current coming to and out of a battery, but an application requires 2 separate sensors; one for incoming and 2nd one for outgoing energy.

Currently I'm measuring and averaging current and voltage every 0.5 seconds with exponential weighted moving average while calculating the energy every minute.

```
batteryEnergy = batteryEnergy + (batteryPower * secondsPassed);
```

So this function runs every 60 seconds, it that uses negative/positive values and resets every midnight.

What would be a good way to have 2 separate values? I'm not sure how to go about the time aspect.

```
if (batteryPower < 0){
    batteryEnergyNegative = batteryEnergyNegative + (batteryPower * secondsPassed);
} else if (batteryPower >= 0){
    batteryEnergyPositive = batteryEnergyPositive + (batteryPower * secondsPassed);
}
```

Comment: The part of the code you posted looks fine, but the devil is in how you are implementing batteryPower and secondsPassed.

Comment: @vir maybe I should change secondsPassed to hoursPassed as that makes more sense. I grab a timestamp in milliseconds since last function call, calculate the difference and convert seconds to hours for kwh. batteryPower is calculated using a voltage divider and an adc, with the current clamp I get the amps and multiply them each 0.5 seconds with ewma algorithm.